# Osculating helix at any point of a space curve

Tags: differential-geometry, 3d, curves

EDIT1:

A 3d curve passes through the origin, the $(T,N,B)$ are tangent, normal and binormal vectors respectively.  In the (T,N) spanned plane of osculation can we parametrize a *helix of osculation* (with given curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$) as

$$ (x,y,z)= \left(\frac{\kappa}{\kappa^2+\tau^2}\sin t,\, \frac{\tau}{\kappa^2+\tau^2}(1-\cos t),\,\frac{t \tau }{2\pi(\kappa^2+\tau^2)}\right)\,$$

(where $t$ is rotation in the projected osculation plane around vector B ) ? If not, how is it correctly parametrized? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to confirm the terminology of _helix of osculation_: The request is for the unit-speed helix of constant curvature $\kappa$ and torsion $\tau$?

Comment: What does it mean when you say “in the $(T,N)$ plane”.

Comment: Have you calculated the curvature and torsion of this curve?

Comment: Yes, they are $ (r,p)/(r^2+p^2)$ respy, where r is the helix radius and pitch $p=2 \pi r $

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I thought we can take unit speed or any other parametrization. Is it right?

Comment: A few notes: (i) Yes, we can assume a unit-speed parametrization. (ii) I was just asking if that particular helix is what was requested. (iii) As Ted notes, some things are not right with the parametrization (e.g., the $\tau$ in the second coordinate should be $\kappa$, there should not be a $2\pi$ in the denominator), though I didn't want to respond in detail before clarifying the definition of osculating helix. :)

Comment: I am not sure about its correct parametrization, so asked the question. The definition of my osculating circular helix at any point must have same curvature and torsion... sorry about delay in this reply.

Answer (score 0):

there are some papers (that also i contributed Öztürk, 2021(Nonlinear transformations)) in the literature which investigated the osculating helix. See (Bhat, 2018) for basics. I have to say that your thought a litte false, firstly you have to guarantee the radius and pitch functions r=k/(k^2+t^2), p=t/(k^2+t^2), where k and t are curvature and torsion of initial curve respectively. There is no need to be axis of the curve is a line. It is defined as axial curve of osculating helix and generally it is not line. Moreover, the base curve not need to be circular. But we can say that our curve has the form a(t)=(rf(t),rg(t),(p/2pi)h(t)), where f,g and h are differentiable functions of t. I hope this will be useful for your further study.